# Read partitioned parquet dataset written by Spark using Dask and pyarrow-dataset engine

Tags: apache-spark, pyarrow, dask-dataframe

I would like to read partitioned parquet datasets written by Spark using Dask and the pyarrow-dataset engine. Ideally, I would be able to provide a list of the parquet files to read. Here is a simple test example exemplifying some errors and unexpected behavior I am experiencing on a larger dataset:

**Write data using spark:**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[("A", 1, 4),
 ("B", 2, 5),
 ("C", 3, 6)
],["id", "col1", "col2"])

home_dir = "/home/xxx/"

df \
.write.format("parquet") \
.mode("overwrite") \
.partitionBy("id") \
.save(home_dir + "parquet_dataset")
```

**Dask with pyarrow engine and a directory works:**

```
import os
from glob import glob
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import dask.dataframe as dd

dd.read_parquet(path=home_dir + "parquet_dataset", engine="pyarrow").compute()
```

> [image: Result1]

**Dask with file list drops the partitioning column**

```
paths = [y for x in os.walk(home_dir + "parquet_dataset") for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0],'*.parquet'))]
dd.read_parquet(path=paths, engine="pyarrow").compute()
```

> [image: Result2]

**Dask with pyarrow-dataset engine results in error:**

```
dd.read_parquet(path=home_dir + "parquet_dataset", engine="pyarrow-dataset")
or
dd.read_parquet(path=paths, engine="pyarrow-dataset") # This is ideally what I am after
```

> ValueError: partition(s) should not exist in columns.
> categories: ['col1', 'col2', 'id'] | partitions: ['id']

**But the following pyarrow methods work fine:**

```
pq.read_table(paths).to_pandas()
ds.dataset(source=paths, partitioning="hive", format="parquet").to_table().to_pandas()
```

Is it possible to get the same behavior using Dask with this format of parquet, partitioning, and idealling using a file list? Any help or ideas on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the third case with `pyarrow-dataset`, that's a known bug that should hopefully be fixed soon, see: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7512

Comment: For the second case, since this works with pyarrow directly, it should also be possible to have this work in dask. Would you like to open an issue about that?

Comment: Thank you @joris. I will open up an issue about this.